# How to handle TransactionInDoubtException

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, sql-server-2008-r2

i have some simple `SELECT` statements and an `INSERT` wrapped in a `using(TransactionScope...)` block. UPDATE: isolation level is ReadCommited
i got the following exception on calling `scope.Complete()`.(see below) 
At the same time the database was under high load caused by another application entirely.
After the fact i found that the `INSERT` statement did in fact execute.
**My question is:** How do i handle this exception in a way that leaves my database in a consistent state ?

i`m looking for a transaction that is always either completed or not completed and never half done.

Exception stack trace:

```
System.Transactions.TransactionInDoubtException: The transaction is in doubt. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadBuffer()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByte()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransaction(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String name, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDelegatedTransaction.SinglePhaseCommit(SinglePhaseEnlistment enlistment)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStateInDoubt.EndCommit(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.CommittableTransaction.Commit()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.InternalDispose()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.Dispose()
```

Comment: What isolationLevel do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A transaction is in doubt when it's unknown whether it has been completed or aborted. The database is still in a consistent state. If you ever get such an exception, you need to access the database to figure out whether the changes has taken place or not, but you can be sure you won't see half of the changes.

Note, I don't know what happens if the component in doubt is the DTC, and you have a distributed transaction - I sure hope Microsoft took care of that, and that a doubtful distributed transaction is still treated as a whole.

See  here: "Specifically, the final outcome of the transaction, whether it commits or aborts, is never known for this transaction."