# TransactionScope in WCF service

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, sql-server-2008-r2, transactionscope

We've a WCF service which is called by clients that run in parallel. I'd like to support a transaction between methodA, methodB, methodC in the service method being called.

However, some of the calls fail with the following error message:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransaction(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String name, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDelegatedTransaction.SinglePhaseCommit(SinglePhaseEnlistment enlistment)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePromotedAborted.PromotedTransactionOutcome(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePromotedEnded.EndCommit(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.CommittableTransaction.Commit()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.InternalDispose()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.Dispose()
```

The WCF service method, has the following code:

```
void Save()
{
  using ( TransactionScope tc = new TransactionScope() )
   {
        methodA(connstring1);
        methodB(connstring1);
        methodC(connstring1);
   }
}

methodA(string connstring)
{
 using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
  { 
    ..Method specific code here 
  }
}

methodB(string connString)
{
  using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
  {
   ..method specific code here.
  }    
}

methodC(string connString)
{
  using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
  {
   ..method specific code here.
  }
}
```

I did dig around a bit and found that this problem was caused in sql server 2005 due to the transactions being promoted to DTC. however, I'm using sql server 2008 r2 sp1 and I still get the error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: is wcf application and database on the same machine?

Comment: Yes. The WCF app and the database are on the same machine for this setup, but would not necessarily be the case for all installations.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559464/how-to-handle-transactionindoubtexception) might help, similar exception.

Comment: where is your `tc.Complete()` in the `save` method at the end of the transaction scope ?